# Javascript event listeners?

Tags: javascript

I find myself looking to add a listener for a particular key, is there a list somewhere of all of the characters which I can listen for? What exactly can and can I not listen for? Surely there is some sort of limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a list of the charCodes.](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx)

Comment: Just adding to alex's answer : 

if you have a particular key in mind, test what keycode it is here : http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in listening for a particular character being typed, use the `keypress` event. You can listen for any character, and obtain the character pressed by its character code. For example, the following illustrates how you can do this for printable keys in all major browsers:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    alert("Character typed: " + String.fromCharCode(charCode));
};
```

If you're interested in listening for a particular physical key being pressed, use the `keyup` and/or `keydown` events and read up about key codes at the definitive reference for all things key-event-related in JavaScript: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score -1):

You are able to listen to onkeypress, onkeyup, onkeydown keyboard events on a DOM object. Then you can determine which key raised the event (from the event args).

Check out this page: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp
for example

Comment: That link gives examples with `onkeypress` as an element attribute. http://w3fools.com

Comment: You cannot listen to a character, only to keyboard events, that is what I wrote, but downvote me, no problem ;)

Comment: @alex: For trivial uses, there's nothing wrong with event handler attributes.

Comment: @Tim Down I guess not, but I reckon the *right way* should be taught first.