# How do I get key values in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so i understand how to get the key value while using an input field... but I am taking about key values that are pressed while your browser isn't focused in any text box or text area.

I am trying to make a onscreen keypad that has buttons for 0, 1, 2, .. 9... however I want the user to be able to press the buttons with the keys on the keyboard.

I've seen this done in some websites, where if you press the S key on the homepage, it will take you to the signin screen. Facebook also does the L key, to like a photo.

So the question is: How do I get the key values in javascript, when the cursor isn't focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using JQuery you just add the event handler to the document...

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
      alert('Handler for .keypress() called. - ' + event.which);
});
```

(From http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-catch-keypress-on-body)

**Edit for zzzzBov's comment...**

From the JQuery [KeyPress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) documentation:

> To determine which character was entered, examine the event object
>   that is passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing
>   properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which
>   property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code.

Comment: `event.which` is probably a better choice

Answer (score 1):

you need to use window.onkeydown and then check for the keys you're interested in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onkeydown

Answer (score 0):

You should listen on key press event.

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    alert("Character typed: " + String.fromCharCode(charCode));
};
```

For more info Look here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921092/javascript-event-listeners)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to the window.  Then in the event handler, you get the `keyCode` property from the passed-in event.  KeyCodes are semi-arbitrary in that they don't directly map to what you might think, so you have to use a table (first result on google: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) to identify the keycodes you care about.

```
window.addEventListener('keypress',function (evt) {
   switch (evt.keyCode) {
       case 48:
           zeroKeyPressed(); break;
       case 49:
           oneKeyPressed(); break;
       ...
   }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a key press event.

Here's an example for your usage:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {

    var key_code, key;

    event = event || window.event; // IE

    key_code = event.charCode || event.keyCode || event.which || 0;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key_code);

    // prevent keys 0-9 from doing what they normally would do
    if (key_code >= 48 && <= 57) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('The user pressed ' + key);
    }

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using plain js, you can use this in your layout.htmlcs, at the beginning:

```
  @{

        <script>
            sessionStorage.setItem("ProductionHostURL", '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductionHostURL"]');
        </script>

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then in your main js file of the layout.htmlcs, you can use this a method liked this:

```
var urlBaseProduction;
var urlBaseDevelopment;

    $(document).ready(function () {
      configureHostEnvironment()
     ....
    }
```

In that method, configure the variables to use in production and development, like this:

```
function configureHostEnvironment(){

    HOST = sessionStorage.getItem("ProductionHostURL")
    if (HOST.length <= 0) {
        alert("Host not configured correctly")
    } else {
        urlBaseProduction= host + '/api/';
        urlBaseDevelopment= host + port + '/api/';
    }
}
```

If you have a suggestion or improvement to this method, please comment.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54444453), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54444435), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54444445)) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*